# Entender código C++/Assembly

Tags: c, c++, socket, assembly

Estou estudando um Node, e nesse processo decidi para ajudar no estudo migrar um sistema em c/c++ para node, porem não estou familiarizado com c/c++ e me apareceu um trecho de código que não estou conseguindo compreender muito bem o que ele faz, poderiam me ajudar ?

```
__declspec(naked) void NKD_AddMessage()
{
    __asm
    {
        PUSH [EBP + 0xC]
        PUSH [EBP + 0x8]
        CALL HKD_AddMessage
        ADD ESP, 0x8

        PUSH EAX

        MOV EAX, 0x41F8C0
        CALL EAX

        POP EAX

        MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP + 0x8], EAX
        MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP - 0x108], EAX

        RETN
    }
}
```

Comment: Vai converter isso para Node? Boa sorte, vai precisar de muita.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Isso não é C++, é assembly (código de máquina). É a sequência de chamada de uma função em assembly.

A sequência de chamada está empilhando parâmetros para a função HKD_AddMessage (instruções PUSH [EBP+...]),e em seguida a função é executada. No retorno de HKD_AddMessage os parâmetros empilhados anteriormente são desempilhandos (ADD SP,8).

Em seguida está sendo chamanda indiretamente (CALL EAX) a função de endereço 0x41F8C0. Esta função deixa um resultado na pilha, que é recuperado no registrador EAX (POP EAX) e salva em dois endereços de memória na área da pilha (PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP etc).

Pode ter algum detalhe que não esteja totalmente certo (estou escrevendo de cabeça, sem consultar nada), mas no geral é isso aí que escrevi.

Comment: Correção: a função HKD_AddMessage deixou um resultado no registrador EAX; este resultado é salvo na pilha (PUSH EAX) antes da chamada da função 0x41F8C0; na volta desta função o valor que foi salvo antes na pilha é restaurado de volta para EAX, e é este valor (retornado pela 1ª chamada de função) que é salvo no nas posiçõe de SS:[EBP + 0x8] e SS:[EBP + 0x108]. Acho que é isso. :)

Comment: Não creio que "Assembly" seja código de máquina, creio que assembly seja uma linguagem de baixo nível, que será montada em código de máquina através de um montador "Assembler". Posso estar errado, mas não creio.

Comment: @MagicHat preciosismo

Comment: Se vc acredita que as definições corretas são preciosismo, deveria rever sua definição de preciosismo.

Comment: @MagicHat obrigado pelo conselho

Comment: Hehe... Se editar o que está errado na sua resposta, posso converter meu voto.

Comment: A crença de que Assembly e código de máquina são a mesma coisa pode trazer uma série de erros teóricos que prejudicariam o entendimento da linguagem. A conversão das instruções em ASM para código de máquina é feita pelo assembler com base nos operadores utilizados, crer que são a mesma coisa traria a falsa crença de que as instruções com operadores diferentes são iguais (como no ASM), e já vi muita gente com dificuldade em entender as instruções por causa disso. Outro exemplo seria o fato do processo de conversão do Assembly para código de máquina ser totalmente "mascarado" como inexistente.

Comment: Só mais um exemplo: Coisas como prefixos e atributos das instruções são difíceis de entender se você achar que o Assembly e código de máquina são iguais, o mesmo vale para o endereçamento usando os bytes ModR/M e SIB. O nível de abstração do Assembly é muito baixo, mas ainda existe abstração.

Comment: hmmm...um dos meu primeiros projetos grandes na faculdade foi escrever um montador...no final do curso escrevemos um compilador...e isso foi no século passado...é lógico que assembly nem sempre se converte 1 pra 1 em código de máquina, mas para  a resposta em questão isso é irrelevante...preciosismo...

Comment: É irrelevante de fato, não estou propondo que isso seja explicado nesta resposta. A questão é unicamente a informação errada de que Assembly é código de máquina. Seria o mesmo erro que afirmar que uma batedeira é um motor. Não é preciosismo, não chega nem perto de ser.

Comment: Você não é obrigado a corrigir o seu erro, apenas estou deixando a correção aqui para outras pessoas que possam ler. Você reduzir a informação correta para a palavra "preciosismo" acaba por atrapalhar o aprendizado de terceiros. Você não precisa corrigir seu erro, mas assim está incentivado que outros cometam o mesmo erro.

Comment: na verdade isso é c++ sim, mesclado com assembly, o assembly é o que está dentro do laço __asm, é difícil ver isso, mais é possivel... quem precisa de um desempenho melhor possivel, é que usa isso, ou simplesmente porque gosta de escovar bits...

Comment: e mais especificamente, c++ da microsoft, "__declspec" é uma extensão do c++ da microsoft, para sinalizar funções para o compilador, usado por exemplo, para dizer qual função vai ser exporta em uma dll